# Remove pastehtml footer in iframe

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe, footer

I made a jQuery slideshow  and the only way to insert it on my website (Jimdo Platform) is by iframe.
The thing is if if I iframe it from pastehtml.com I'll get they're footer on top of my jQuery slideshow and it will become scrollable even with `scrolling=no`.

Is there some kind of way in which I can show only the jQuery content or to trim that footer?

Answer (score 0):

Create a div surrounding your iframe, set his width/height to the slideshow width/height.
Set the iframe width and height larger than div.
Then set overflow to hidden to the div.

i.e.:

```
slideshow inside pastehtml width/height: 500/200;

iframe width/height: 700/300;
div width/height: 500/200;
div overflow: hidden;
```

if there are other elements you want to hide, position iframe absolutely and move it to show only the slides.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, you can't. Due to cross-site scripting restrictions that modern browsers include for security reasons, whatever javascript and css you put on your web page can only affect the contents of iframes if the iframe is loading something else from the same site (or a site that has a crossdomain.xml that allows it, but that almost certainly isn't the case here).

The workarounds that come to mind are hosting the slideshow on your own website, or bouncing the slideshow off a proxy on your website - I'd recommend the former.